# Select retorna 2 linhas por conta do GROUP BY

Tags: sql, pl-sql

O código a baixo retorna a quantidade de marcados e a quantidade de atendidos, mas ao adicionar o `CASE` para me trazer a quantidade de faltas ele separa a linha dos atendidos da linha dos faltosos, isso tudo por conta do `group by` que tem que ser feito com a coluna `IAC.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA`.

Como faço para isso não acontecer?

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(AC.DT_AGENDA)        AS DATA_AGENDA,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA        AS EMPRESA,
    AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS CD_UNID_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE)     AS TOTAL_MARCADOS,
    COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO)  AS ATENDIDOS,
    (COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO) / COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE) * 100) PERC_ATENDIDO,
    (CASE WHEN IAC.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA = 'F' THEN COUNT(IAC.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA) END) AS FALTA

FROM AGENDA_CENTRAL AC
    INNER JOIN IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL   IAC   ON AC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL      = IAC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL
    INNER JOIN UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO UA    ON UA.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO = AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN MULTI_EMPRESAS      ME    ON ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA       = AC.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA

WHERE IAC.NM_PACIENTE IS NOT NULL
AND ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA  = 2
AND AC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL = 12643

GROUP BY AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA,
    AC.DT_AGENDA,
    IAC.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA
```

**Resultado:**

```
MARCADOS    ATENDIDOS   PERC_ATENDIDO   FALTA
 9              9           100%          0
 4              0            0            4
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
MARCADOS    ATENDIDOS   PERC_ATENDIDO   FALTA
    13          9            69%          4
```

Comment: tem 8 colunas no select, e 4 no resultado... ?

Comment: O problema não são as colunas, eu só resumi porque a quantidade de colunas são essas mesmo, o que está ocorrendo é que o resultador retorna duas linhas, ele separa os faltosos dos atendidos, eu não quero isso, quero que ele só adicione a linha de falta a quantidade de faltosos. Eu explico isso no exemplo a baixo de resultado esperado.

Comment: justamente, as colunas que você está retornando fazem a diferença no resultado com group by

Comment: Tem alguma ideia de como resolvo isso?

Comment: primeira coisa é limitar o select só nas colunas que você precisa, se já está assim, coloque o resultado completo que está sendo retornado

Comment: Uma possibilidade nesse caso é fazer o count das faltas dentro dum subselect ao invés de fazer no select principal. Do jeito que está estruturado no momento, o group by é realmente necessário

Comment: basicamente, o resultado que você está tendo, é uma linha para cada `AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA,
    AC.DT_AGENDA,
    IAC.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA` e, em alguma dessas colunas, um valor é diferente do outro, por isso não agrupa.

Comment: @Andrey seguindo sua ideia realmente funcionou. Resposta publicada.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta, baseada no comentário de @Andrey.

Pois efetuando o subselect foi possível retornar o resultado esperado. 
Segue a baixo o código corrigido.

```
SELECT
    DATA_AGENDA,
    EMPRESA,
    CD_UNID_ATENDIMENTO,
    UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    TOTAL_MARCADOS,
    ATENDIDOS,
    TOTAL_MARCADOS - ATENDIDOS AS FALTA,
    ROUND(PERC_ATENDIDO,0) PERC_ATENDIDO


FROM (SELECT
      TRUNC(AC.DT_AGENDA)        AS DATA_AGENDA,
      ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA        AS EMPRESA,
      AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS CD_UNID_ATENDIMENTO,
      UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
      COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE)     AS TOTAL_MARCADOS,
      COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO)  AS ATENDIDOS,
      (COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO) / COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE) * 100) PERC_ATENDIDO
      ,(SELECT (CASE WHEN IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA = 'F' THEN COUNT(IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA) END) FALTA

       FROM IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL) FALTA



FROM AGENDA_CENTRAL AC
    INNER JOIN IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL   IAC   ON AC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL      = IAC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL
    INNER JOIN UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO UA    ON UA.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO = AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN MULTI_EMPRESAS      ME    ON ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA       = AC.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA

WHERE IAC.NM_PACIENTE IS NOT NULL
AND ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA  = 2
AND AC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL = 12643
```

Retirado o IAC.TP_PRESENCA_FALTA do GROUP BY

```
GROUP BY AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA,
    AC.DT_AGENDA)
```

Comment: Xará, me ajudou com essa ai também.